# Linux system crashed

Tags: linux, crash

Recently, my industrial computer has crashed many times, sometimes once a day, sometimes once every few days.
Syslog:
[image: image of log text]
[image: image of log text]

OS:Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)

```
uname -a
Linux debian 4.19.288-rt126 #4 SMP PREEMPT RT Mon Jul 31 15:30:07 CST 2023 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Text should be posted as text, not as images: Accessibility, If it can not be read by a blind person, then it is hard to read by everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Use `memtes86+` for testing RAM, `fsck` and `smartctl` for testing file system and hard drive, respectively, and `stress` for running a CPU performance check - just to name a few diagonostic tools.

In general, I'd start with verifying that your disks are not full (`df`) and then check for RAM and hard disk errors.

A bit more specific for you:

Since there seem to be problems with `alloc` and `kmalloc`, as your logs state, my wild guess goes towads RAM and/or hard drive problems. But as said: ensure that `/` has free space left first.

Comment: Thanks，I will try your suggestions.